# Material-UI Drawer and Topbar transition animation not working when toggled after implementing Redux/Redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I have implemented the Material-UI Drawer in a Gastby.js project and the transition animation worked fine until I have introduced redux and redux-toolkit to the table. The toggling went well but the animation of the transition is not working anymore. My guess is that the drawer and the topbar re-renders after the store state has changed (not so sure), so I have tried gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-browser.js. Still nothing changed.

**gatsby-ssr.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./src/store/store";

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    return <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>;
};
```

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./src/store/store";

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    return <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>;
};
```

**layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import {Box} from "@mui/material";
import Topbar from "./topbar/Topbar";
import Drawer from "./drawer/Drawer";


export default function Layout ({children}){
    return (
        <Box>
            <Topbar/>
            <Drawer/>
            {children}
        </Box>
    );
};
```

**drawer.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Divider, IconButton, List, styled, useTheme} from "@mui/material";
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import {ChevronLeft, ChevronRight} from "@mui/icons-material";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {layoutSelector} from "../../store/layoutStore";
import {toggleDrawerOpen} from "../../store/layoutStore/index";


const Index = () => {

    const {drawerWidth, drawerOpen} = useSelector(layoutSelector);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
        width: drawerWidth,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
    });

    const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: `calc(${theme.spacing(9)} + 1px)`,
        },
    });

    const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    }));

    const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
        ({ theme, open }) => ({
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            color: "#fff",
            ...(open && {
                ...openedMixin(theme),
                '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
            }),
            ...(!open && {
                ...closedMixin(theme),
                '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
            }),
        }),
    );

    console.log('re-render')
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <Drawer variant="permanent" open={drawerOpen}>
            <DrawerHeader>
                <IconButton
                    onClick={() => dispatch(toggleDrawerOpen())}
                >
                    {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRight  color={'white'}/> : <ChevronLeft color={'white'} />}
                </IconButton>
            </DrawerHeader>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {/*{['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (*/}
                {/*    <ListItem button key={text}>*/}
                {/*        <ListItem>*/}
                {/*            {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}*/}
                {/*        </ListItem>*/}
                {/*        <ListItemText primary={text} />*/}
                {/*    </ListItem>*/}
                {/*))}*/}
            </List>
            <Divider />

        </Drawer>
    )
}

export default Index;
```

**topbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Box, IconButton, styled, Toolbar, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import {Menu} from "@mui/icons-material";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {layoutSelector, toggleDrawerOpen} from "../../store/layoutStore";

const Index = () => {

    const {drawerWidth, drawerOpen} = useSelector(layoutSelector);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
        shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
    })(({theme, open}) => ({
        color: theme.palette.primary,
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        ...(open && {
            marginLeft: drawerWidth,
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
            transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            }),
        }),
    }));
    return (
        <AppBar position="fixed" open={drawerOpen}>
            <Toolbar color={'white'} style={{background: 'white'}}>
                <IconButton
                    color="secondary"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={() => dispatch(toggleDrawerOpen())}
                    edge="start"
                    // sx={{
                    //     marginRight: '36px',
                    //     ...(true && { display: 'none' }),
                    // }}
                >
                    <Menu/>
                </IconButton>

            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Index;
```

I don't know what I am missing here. Help please, thank you!